# Entity enum is not exported

Tags: jhipster

When generating an Entity (`Configuration`) containing an enumeration (`Status`), the Angular model looks like this :

```
const enum Status {
    'DRAFT',
    'DONE',
    'ARCHIVED'
}

export class Configuration implements BaseEntity {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public json?: string,
        public status?: EventConfigurationStatus,
    ) {
    }
}
```

The problem is that the enum is not exported. Because I want to use the enum on its own, I add the `export` keyword. This is hard-coded in `_entity.model.ts` at [line 86](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/entity/templates/client/angular/src/main/webapp/app/entities/_entity.model.ts#L86)

Won't you think that having `export` by default would be better ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it makes sense.

Beside you use case, it would be also required for JHipster entity generator in order to generate compiling code if you had a Customer entity with a relationship with Configuration and using `"otherEntityField": "status"`.